# Generating statistics for a time-sensitive web application

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

We're running a very time-sensitive web application (response time has to be below 100ms), with a lot of requests (about 200k requests per minute at peak). The architecture is really simple: a load balancer, several web servers, running apache and php, and a database running MySQL.

We also need to be able to generate statistics based on those requests.

About a year ago when we were serving a tenth of our current traffic volume, we developed some  bash/python scripts to periodically dump the logs from mysql, trasnfer them to another server, import them again and run the statistics there, the idea being to have the production servers do as little as possible so that we could have a low response time.

As you might imagine, that solution didn't scale very well, and at the moment, the stat server is barely keeping up. We need a way to generate statistics in real time.

Do you have any experiences with this kind of a setup? Our idea at the moment is to have the web servers call the stats servers in real time on each request.

The two main problems are:

- how should we approach this so that the response time doesn't increase too much
- the stats server or server has to handle all the requests from all the webheads / or it needs to be able to scale horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a database?  Calculate mean and standard deviation in memory on the fly as requests come in.  You won't have any latency that way, and you can have access to values using an MBean console.

This can only work on an individual server, not a cluster.

Comment: is MBean Java specific? we're using PHP. but you gave me an idea: we could generate stats on the fly and store them in APC, and have a cron job collect them periodically

Comment: Sorry, MBean is Java-specific.

Answer (score 2):

1) Separate MySQL server
Why dont you connect directly to another MySQL server and write stats there? From the top of my head at this moment I would create table for each day so I could easily move older tables out when not needed. Problem here is lack of horizontal scalability though ...

2) NoSQL
Maybe you should use MongoDB or Redis for things like this? They are much faster since they are memory based and offer sharding.

3) Independent stats server
If you are serving HTML you can add javascript method to call script (and small img inside  tags with url for users having javascript disabled) on remote server which can write statistics from params given in URL. This would offload everything from application servers totally and you can try suggestion #1 or #2 there ...

Comment: 1. I think connecting to another server would increase response time too much. 2. we did think of nosql, but we don't have much experience with either redis or mongodb. the main issue is that we're not sure how many ms would a redis call add to the reponse time. 3. not really an option for us as most of the time we're not serving requests to browsers

Comment: 1) How much time it takes to connect to current mysql server? I checked and we have around 2-5ms for connecting ...

2) Dont know, I am using MongoDB only for testing purposes now and on localhost but you should be able to test it very easily . Installing mongo is easy and fast, connecting+inserting to it is a short script with max 20 lines of code (for testing purpose use it as a procedural PHP snippet )

3) I thought it was since you would be using Google Anaylitics in that case :)